# Glade C++ app, GUI design not the same at Runtime

Tags: c++, gtk, codeblocks, glade

Im very new to gui programming in linux and Im stumbling at the 1st hurdle, Im using glade to design a *form* (i come from windows background) it looks completly different in Glade than it does when I run the compiled program.
[heres a screen grab of them](http://img841.imageshack.us/i/gladeb.png/)

see link as they wont let me post images

heres the c++

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void close_app(GtkWidget* widget,gpointer user_data) {
 gtk_main_quit();
}
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
 GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder;
 GtkWidget *mainwin;
 gtk_set_locale();

 gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

 gtkBuilder= gtk_builder_new();
 gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder,"test2.glade",NULL);
 gtk_builder_connect_signals ( gtkBuilder, NULL );
 mainwin= GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder,"window1"));
 g_object_unref ( G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder) );

 gtk_widget_show_all ( mainwin );

 gtk_main ();

 return 0;
}
```

im on debian squeeze and im using libgtk2.0-dev version 2.20 libgnome2.24  <- I dont even know if this mught be the problem?

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing in the empty spaces in your HBox and VBox. If there are no other widgets taking up the space, then your button will expand to fill all available space. Put some other widgets in your window if you don't want the button to fill it. Sizing and placement work differently in GTK than they do in other toolkits, the idea is to build a user interface that still looks good when the user resizes the window or when the UI strings change length because the user is using your application in another language.

See the [relevant section of the GTK tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/c354.html) or [this other tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtklayoutmanagement/).